# How to implement a huge matrix in C

Tags: c, memory, matrix

I'm writing a program for a numerical simulation in C. Part of the simulation are spatially fixed nodes that have some float value to each other node. It is like a directed graph. However, if two nodes are too far away, (farther than some cut-off length a) this value is 0.

To represent all these "correlations" or float values, I tried to use a 2D array, but since I have 100.000 and more nodes, that would correspond to 40GB memory or so.

Now, I am trying to think of different solustions for that problem. I don't want to save all these values on the harddisk. I also don't want to calculate them on the fly. One idea was some sort of sparse matrix, like the one one can use in Matlab.

Do you have any other ideas, how to store these values?

I am new to C, so please don't expect too much experience.

Thanks and best regards,
Jan Oliver

Comment: What about some kind of hash/map where the key is (row x col)? It would only have as many elements as there are entries in the matrix with a non-zero value.

Comment: It's not really a specific question... Yeah, sparse matrices. Go look up some algorithms.... Maybe with some details on the percentage of nulll nodes in the matrix, or more information about the simulation, maybe someone could suggest other solutions than a grah representation.

Comment: ... for example, what do you want to do with this matrix?

Comment: If you have <40GB RAM, don't want to save the values to the HDD and don't want to calculate them on the fly, then the only other option I can see is to store only non-zero values and hope that they all fit into RAM.

Comment: Also - isn't the "distance" between two nodes mutual?   Therefore rather than n*n distances, there will be 2(n-1) which will in this case need 774kB

Comment: @SlappyTheFish The question was "how to store these values", not which values to store.

Comment: @Jim - sure, which is why I just posted it as a comment, but I can't see how else to solve it :-)

Comment: @SlappyTheFish Rather than n*n distances, there are n*(n-1)/2 distances. Well, actually there are n*(m-1)/2 distances, where m is the average number of nodes within the cutoff distance from a node.

Comment: There is one additional parameter in each node, that also influences my correlation value. That's why this graph is directed.

Comment: If these are nodes in space, why would it be directed? Why would the correlation value between a and b be different from the correlation value between b and a? Also, is there any need to store distances/coordinates, or are they only used to determine whether the correlation value is non-zero?

Comment: @janoliver Oh, I think I misunderstood. So, each node has a different parameter so the correlations aren't symmetric. But do the parameters need to be stored? You want to minimize the size of these nodes to hold only what you need during the simulation. Anyway, I think we've covered the bases; good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many nodes, on average, are within the cutoff distance for a given node determines your memory requirement and tells you whether you need to page to disk. The solution taking the least memory is probably a hash table that maps a pair of nodes to a distance. Since the distance is the same each way, you only need to enter it into the hash table once for the pair -- put the two node numbers in numerical order and then combine them to form a hash key. You could use the Posix hsearch/hcreate/hdestroy functions for the hash table, although they are less than ideal.

Comment: that is a good idea. One node is in average connected to 0,2% of the other nodes. This depends on the parameters.

Comment: I am a little concerned about the performance of the lookup process, though. That is actually much more important than for example the creation of the matrix/hashmap, since the latter is done only once...

Comment: @janoliver So that's 200 of the 100,000 nodes? On speed: hash lookup is O(1) but the constant time can be large, especially when you're short on memory. (How much do you have?) Perhaps best would be an array of nodes with each node containing a list of nearby nodes sorted by node number; the binary lookup would take about 9 comparisons for 200 nodes. That's easy to implement and you might want to start with it and only consider something else if necessary.

Comment: P.S. The discussion presumes that you need to do lookups by node number, but that's not clear. You need to establish what your simulation requires of the node table. If you only enumerate nodes, never look them up, then linear arrays are definitely the way to go.

Comment: Well, then in this list of neighbors I would also have to store that correlation value I need. So I would have to use a struct containing the neighbor-node (or it's index) and that float value... But yes, that might be the easiest thing.

Comment: No, I need to look up specific node-to-node edges a lot. So the quick lookup of certain elements is the most important part.

Answer (score 2):

A sparse matrix approach sounds ideal for this. The [Wikipedia article on sparse matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) discusses several approaches to implementation.

Answer (score 2):

A sparse adjacency matrix is one idea, or you could use an adjacency list, allowing your to only store the edges which are closer than your cutoff value.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the idea. After a quick look on these lists, it seems that a simple float value referenced by two indices is less memory consuming than one of these list items..

Answer (score 1):

You could also hold a list for each node, which contains the other nodes this node is related to. You would then have an overall number of list entries of 2**k*, where *k* is the number of non-zero values in the virtual matrix.

Implementing the whole system as a combination of hashes/sets/maps is still expected to be acceptable with regard to speed/performance compared to a "real" matrix allowing random access.

**edit**: This solution is one possible form of an implementation of a sparse matrix. (See also Jim Balter's note below. Thank you, Jim.)

Comment: Surely 2(k-1) because a node won't link to itself?   See my comment on the main question, I agree this is the way to solve it.

Comment: Note that a list in each node where each entry in the list contains a node number and a non-zero distance is a form sparse matrix, where each node list is a row (or column).

Comment: @SlappyTheFish Flinsch wrote "k is the number of non-zero values in the virtual matrix" -- the diagonal is all zeros in the virtual matrix, so k already excludes those entries. The list actually includes k entries, where each entry has two values, a node number and a distance.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for your notes. I totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use sparse matrices if possible. In scipy, we have support for sparse matrices, so that you can play in python, although to be honest sparse support still has rough edges.

If you have access to matlab, it will definitely be better ATM.

Without using sparse matrix, you could think about using memap-based arrays so that you don't need 40 Gb of RAM, but it will still be slow, and only really make sense if you have a low degree of sparsity (say if 10-20 % of your 100000x100000 matrix has items in it, then full arrays will actually be faster and maybe even take less space than sparse matrices).